# setting array as state not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

In this component, I am drawing text on an image inside a canvas. I want to track all the text and store some of their property but When I hold them inside a state they don't update in UI but update inside dev tools. But when array length is more than one it updates on UI but just one item. If my state array is [1,2]. Inside UI it only shows [1].but inside react dev tools it's fine. But if I store texts in a global array it just works fine.

**Component**

```jsx
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles/Generator.css";
//Why this one Work but not state
let textArr = [];
let startX, startY;
export default function Generator() {
  //const [textArr,setTextArr]=useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [isClear, setIsClear] = useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [offsets, setOffsets] = useState({
    selectedText: -1,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
  });
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { item } = state;
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  let contextRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    setOffsets({
      ...offsets,

      offsetX: canvasRef.current.offsetLeft,
      offsetY: canvasRef.current.offsetTop,
    });
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    contextRef.current = context;
    //Our first draw
    let asp = item.width / item.height;
    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400 / asp;
    const meme = new Image();
    meme.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
    meme.src = item.url;
    meme.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(meme, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      setImage(meme);
    };
  }, [isClear]);
  const addText = () => {
    if (text.length < 1) return;
    var y = textArr.length * 20 + 20;
    // get the text from the input element

    var t = {
      text: text,
      x: 50,
      y: y + 70,
    };

    // calc the size of this text for hit-testing purposes
    contextRef.current.font = "20px arial";
    t.width = contextRef.current.measureText(t.text).width;
    t.height = 20;
    //setState([...textArr,t])
    textArr.push(t);
    draw();

    setText("");
  };

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsets.offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsets.offsetY);
    textArr.map((i, index) => {
      if (textHittest(startX, startY, index)) {
        return setOffsets({ ...offsets, selectedText: index });
      }
    });
  };
  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (offsets.selectedText < 0) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    let mouseX = parseInt(e.pageX - offsets.offsetX);
    let mouseY = parseInt(e.pageY - offsets.offsetY);
    var text = textArr[offsets.selectedText];
    text.y += dy;
    startX = mouseX;
    draw();
  };
  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOffsets({ ...offsets, selectedText: -1 });
  };
  function textHittest(x, y, textIndex) {
    var text = textArr[textIndex];
    const isTrue =
      x >= text.x &&
      x <= text.x + text.width &&
      y >= text.y - text.height &&
      y <= text.y;
    return isTrue;
  }

  function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOffsets({ ...offsets, selectedText: -1 });
  }
  const draw = () => {
    contextRef.current.drawImage(
      image,
      0,
      0,
      canvasRef.current.width,
      canvasRef.current.height
    );

    textArr.length > 0 &&
      textArr.map((i) => {
        contextRef.current.fillText(i.text, i.x, i.y);
        return;
      });
  };
  const download = () => {
    let img = canvasRef.current
      .toDataURL("image/png", 1.0)
      .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "my-image.png";
    link.href = img;
    link.click();
  };
  return (
    <div className="generator">
      <div className="generator__container">
        <div className="generator__header">
          <h1 className="home__title">Meme-Generator</h1>
          <a href="/" className="home__link-top">
            back
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="generator__content">
          <div className="generator__left">
            <canvas
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
              onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
              onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              ref={canvasRef}
              className="canvas"
            />
            <div className="generator__btn-container">
              <button onClick={download} className="generator__btn">
                Download
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="generator__right">
            <h3 className="generator__sub-title">Add Text to Meme</h3>
            <label className="generator__label" htmlFor="text1">
              Enter Text
            </label>
            <input
              value={text}
              className="generator__input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter text.."
              onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              onClick={addText}
              className="generator__btn generator__btn--text"
            >
              Add Text
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**State**

```js
//setting array like this work
let textArr = [];
let startX, startY;
export default function Generator() {
  //setting state like this doesn't work
  //const [textArr,setTextArr]=useState([]); 
  return (....)
}
```

**Add Text function**

```js
const addText = () => {
  if (text.length < 1) return;
  var y = textArr.length * 20 + 20;

  var t = {
    text: text,
    x: 50,
    y: y + 70,
  };
  contextRef.current.font = "20px arial";
  t.width = contextRef.current.measureText(t.text).width;
  t.height = 20;
  //state updating like this don't effect on UI but it update on devtools
  //setState([...textArr,t])
  //This like work just fine
  textArr.push(t);
  draw();

  setText("");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

State updates are async, but you call your "draw" function right after you set new state (when the state was not updated yet)

If you want draw function to work every time the textArr is updated you need to use the effect hook. Should work like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  draw();
}, [textArr]);
```

if your draw function depends on other values you should include them to dependencies array too (right after textArr)